# C++ evaluating an arithmetic expression in RPN format using ADT stack

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stack, adt

Write a program that uses an ADT Stack to evaluate arithmetic expressions in RPN format. The contents of the stack should be displayed on the screen during evaluation. The allowed arithmetic operators are +, -, x, and /.

What I have done so far:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string.h> 

using namespace std;
 
struct Stack
{
    int top;
    unsigned cap;
    int* arr;
};

struct Stack* createStackFun(unsigned capacity)
{
    struct Stack* s = (struct Stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    if (!s) return NULL;
    s->top = -1;
    s->cap = capacity;
    s->arr = (int*)malloc(s->cap * sizeof(int));
    if (!s->arr) return NULL;
    return s;
}

int isEmpty(struct Stack* stack)
{
    return stack->top == -1;
}

char peek(struct Stack* stack)
{
    return stack->arr[stack->top];
}

char pop(struct Stack* stack)
{
    if (!isEmpty(stack))
        return stack->arr[stack->top--];
    return '$';
}

void push(struct Stack* stack, char op)
{
    stack->arr[++stack->top] = op;
}

int postfixEvaluation(char* exp)
{
    // Create a stack of capacity equal to expression size 
    struct Stack* stack = createStackFun(strlen(exp));
    int i;
    // See if stack was created successfully 
    if (!stack) return -1;
    // Scan all characters one by one 
    for (i = 0; exp[i]; ++i)
    {
        // If the scanned character is an operand (number here), push it to the stack. 
        if (isdigit(exp[i]))
            push(stack, exp[i] - '0');
        // If the scanned character is an operator, pop two elements from stack apply the operator 
        else
        {
            int val1 = pop(stack);
            int val2 = pop(stack);
            switch (exp[i])
            {
            case '+': 
                push(stack, val2 + val1); 
                break;
            case '-': 
                push(stack, val2 - val1); 
                break;
            case '*': 
                push(stack, val2 * val1); 
                break;
            case '/': 
                push(stack, val2 / val1); 
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return pop(stack);
}

int main()
{
    char expression[] = "74*+8-";
    cout << "Postfix Evaluation: " << postfixEvaluation(expression);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem:

I am not sure if this is correct and I don't know if there is a way to shorten the code or make it better.

Comment: If you need a code review, there is a site dedicated to that: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you considered testing your code?

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems:

- if stack is not created successfully you `return -1;` from `postfixEvaluation()`, but you don't handle that in the main function, it should probably lead to some error message and `return -1;` in main
- you are pushing digits into stack one by one - so that 74 on input becomes 7
  and 4 as separate numbers on the stack, doesn't it?
- you could make a default
  label inside switch inside postfixEvaluation to handle illegal
  operator in input
- you are malloc'ing stack and array inside stack, but you are not freeing the memory (you can use [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) to check for memory leaks)

If you need some reference to check against, which also includes parentheses and functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm#The_algorithm_in_detail